# Where to download, or find a list of all the Windows updates?

Tags: windows, windows-update, slipstream

I have a Windows 7 SP1 installation disc.

After I install Windows, there are about 160 updates to download.

Is there a way to get a list or to download all of those updates so that I can create a new Windows 7 installation disc with the updates slipstreamed?

I know that I can go one by one through the updates and download them but that would take a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Full guide found on first page of Google results: http://www.pcworld.com/article/239634/how_to_speed_up_windows_7_installs_with_slipstreaming_and_usb.html

Comment: i know how to slipstream and how to slipstream sp1 but im looking for a way to slipstream all the updates after sp1 up until now that doesn't require me manually going through each update and downloading them one by one

Comment: Something like offline update packages? http://download.wsusoffline.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samual got me on the right track.
I found [Windows Update Downloader](https://web.archive.org/web/20220526155921/https://www.windowsupdatesdownloader.com/).

This allows you to download all the updates. and to integrate them into the windows 7 installation cd i used this guide http://4sysops.com/archives/use-dism-to-slipstream-updates/ which shows how to integrate updates into the cd.

I hope this helps others with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the official Microsoft® Update Catalog (https://catalog.update.microsoft.com).

> **What is Microsoft Update Catalog?**
>
> It's a service from Microsoft that provides a listing of updates that
>   can be distributed over a corporate network. You can use it as a
>   one-stop location for finding Microsoft software updates, drivers, and
>   hotfixes.