# Updating Windows Patches on a bootable USB

Tags: windows, windows-update

I used WinToFlash to clone a Windows CD to a USB to make it bootable.

Is there a way I can push Windows Updates to the USB so WU does not take as long to run?

Comment: You can use something like [WSUS Offline Update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) to simply handle everything offline.

Comment: Also see [Where to download, or find a list of all the Windows updates](http://superuser.com/questions/788075/where-to-download-or-find-a-list-of-all-the-windows-updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best method of achieving a bootable windows install with updates already installed is to create a custom version of the installer. Its possible using third party tools such as WinReducer.

There is a tutorial/example here: **http://www.howtogeek.com/169522/customize-your-windows-8-installation-disc-and-slipstream-updates-with-winreducer/**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Including the whole page would bloat the answer far too much. Also this tutorial is purely an example as there are different vectors to tackling this issue. hence why I have included the name of the tool.

Comment: That is entirely your choice not to improve this answer.  If you include the tutorial, it will provide me the ability, to reverse my vote I originally issued.